# How should be InterruptedException handled for CountDownLatch.wait

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupt

How should be `InterruptedException` be handled during waiting of `CountDownLatch.wait`?

I need to be sure that `CountDownLatch.wait` will wait all other thread to be finished, but if during waiting exception will be thrown, how should i deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the method is `await()`, not `wait()`. `wait()` is a method from java.lang.Object, which does something completely different.

You won't get any InterruptedException unless you decide, from another thread, to interrupt the thread being blocked in `latch.await()` (by calling `thread.interrupt()`). And since you decide to interrupt the thread, you should know what to do when the thread is interrupted. Usually, you decide to interrupt a thread when you want it to finish what he's doing as soon as possible, and stop running.

Comment: ok got, it if will be thrown only by "my" possible code, i know what to do)